# offset().top is null or not an object error in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the live demo of the code here: [**LIVE DEMO**](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/c.php?zh=loadPage)

What I am looking to do is when the `1` box is clicked it should scroll to the first section, when the `2` box is clicked it should scroll to the second section and so forth. But when I click on the numbers, I receive the following error:

`offset().top is null or not an object`

My JQuery looks like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".pointto").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("Hover");
    });
    $(".pointto").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("Hover").removeClass("Pressed");
    });
    $(".pointto").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).addClass("Pressed");
    });
    $(".pointto").mouseup(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("Pressed");
    });
$(document).on('click', '.Hover, .Pressed, .pointto', function() { 
    var nn = $(this).attr('id').replace('s', '');
    alert('a[name="'+nn+'"]'); //clicking on 1 gives me <a name="01">
    t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top; //t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:t},800);
});
});
```

HTML sample:

```
<a id="s01" class="pointto">1</a> //clickable link
...
...
...
<a name="01">1. About</a> //target
```

Any idea how to resolve that error?

**Update: [RESOLVED]**

```
$(document).on('click', '.Hover, .Pressed, .pointto', function() { 
    var nn = $(this).attr('id').replace('s', '');
    alert('a[name="'+nn+'"]');
    t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top; //t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:t},800);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this `t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]')[0].offset().top;` ?

Comment: In your dev console, what do you get when you enter $('a[name="'+nn+'"]'); I think the selector can't find an element

Comment: Sounds like your selector isn't matching any elements

Comment: @Ghillied If that edit is done then I receive an `missing ')'` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted html, this is what you have:

```
var nn = $(this).attr('id').replace('a', '');
```

Since the `id` is `s01`, `nn` is now set to `s01`, since there are no "a"s in the id, nothing is replaced

```
t = $('a[name="'+nn+'"]').offset().top;
```

You then look for an `a` with a `name` of `s01`.  Your anchor does not have this name, your anchor is named `1`.  The offset of nothing is null, so you then try to take the `top` property of null.

Comment: your selector was fine before, your name value was just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is returning empty. Your target elements have names such as "1", "2", etc. and your selector is trying to find "s01", "s02" etc.

Your code should be `var nn = $(this).attr('id').replace('s0', '');` or rename the elements you want to scroll to appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector when doing `$('<a name="'+nn+'">')` is wrong. it should be :

```
$('a[name="'+nn+'"]')
```